# Copying Filtered Range getting overflow error

Tags: excel, vba

Failure counts of failed products counted by `COUNTIF` Function. Results of `counts > 0` are auto filtered. Filtered results to be pasted to sheet3. Limited range being copied for test of program logic. Getting `Run time error 6 Overflow` on the code line:  `numbElements = targetRng.End(xlDown).Row` 
Related information appended below. Can someone point out the mistake.

[image: Sheet before auto filter]
[image: sheet after auto filter]

```
 Sub test()

    Dim targetRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set targetRng = Sheets(3).Range("a1")
    Range("A1", Range("A999").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=targetRng, Unique:=True

    Dim numbElements As Integer
    numbElements = targetRng.End(xlDown).Row
    Dim arr() As String

    ReDim arr(1 To numbElements) As String

    For i = 1 To numbElements
        arr(i) = targetRng.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get error with exactly that code? It should not happen if you filter maximum `998` rows. If the number of rows in result range is higher than `32767`, than you will get `Integer` overflow. Change `numbElements` and `i` to `Long`.

Comment: After changing `numbElements` and `I` to `Long` overflow error is corrected but program prints only cell `A1` to 'Product' . Rest of the range either filtered or non filtered is not getting printed. Those cells are blank. Still there is something wrong in the coding.

Comment: Hi skkakkar, I think @user3964075's answer fixed this specific problem (he showld provide it as an answer to be accepted, then you could open a different question for the next issue)

Comment: @paul bica Noted please. Thanks.

Comment: @user3964075 please look into recent comments on the post.

Comment: @skkakkar if you post new question, you should prepare a better explanation: what is 'Product', why do you fill array in a loop and do nothing with it,

Comment: @user3964075 Since I have decided not to ask question on this particular case, I wish to explain practical utility of my question approach, 1000 candidates called by company for interview assessed by three persons for suitability in yes or no form , Column A contains to have Names, Column B to have bio-data reference. Filtered list of more than 2 acceptance to be copied to separate sheet with only Name and Bio reference. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum `Integer` value in VBA is `32767` `(2^15-1)`. Assigning row number to Integer may cause overflow.

You should change your `numbElements` and `i` variable definitions to `Long`. Maximum value of `Long` is `2147483647` `(2^31-1)`.